# How to select values of tuples inside tuples?

Tags: python

I have a tuple called **params** which included two other tuples. The tutorial I got this code from accesses the tuples inside the tuple with `self.params.printlog`. However, that is not working for me. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
class TestStrategy():
    params = (
        ('maperiod', 15),
        ('printlog', False),
    )

    def log(self, txt, dt=None, doprint=False):
        if self.params.printlog or doprint:
            dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
            print('%s, %s' % (dt.isoformat(), txt))
```

**Description in the tutorial of what is done:**

> I thought the same, but it's not a dict and not a named tuple. It
>   would a bit unpractical to hardcode some of the values in the strategy
>   and have no chance to change them easily. Parameters come in handy to
>   help.
>
> Definition of parameters is easy and looks like:
>
> ```
> params = (('myparam', 27), ('exitbars', 5),)
> ```
>
> Being this a standard Python tuple with some tuples inside it, the
>   following may look more appealling to some:
>
> ```
> params = (
>     ('myparam', 27),
>     ('exitbars', 5),)
> ```

Comment: you can't even access the value using `self.params["printlog"]`

Comment: Did the tutorial use a `namedtuple`?

Comment: In your code `params` is a tuple of a tuple but `self.params["printlog"]` will fail. Are you sure what you have isn't actually a `dict`? `self.params[1][1]` in the code you have given us will work. In any case, it sounds like what you want is a named tuple: `from collections import namedtuple; Params = namedtuple('Params', 'maperiod, printlog')'; params = Params(15, False)`. Access with `self.params.printlog`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I added some details from the tutorial to my question. It seems that he is actually using a tuple inside a tuple and is able to access them in the mentioned way (I don't get why)

Answer (score 2):

Use `params[0][0]` for accessing maperiod

And similarly,  `params[1][0]` for printlog

Alternatively, you can also use a named tuple

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment? Apart from your love that you just bestowed on me

Comment: OP wants to access the values (index 1) not the keys (index 0) :)

Comment: Hmm. OK. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so there are three main data structures at play here.

---

There is a tuple, which is what you have in the code you've shown us:

```
params = (('maperiod', 15), ('printlog', False))
```

You have to use `int`s to access, like to get the `'printlog'` value use `params[1][1]` and the `maperiod` value use `params[0][1]`.

```
params[0][1] == 15
params[1][1] == False
```

---

There are dicts which is what is sounds like how you accessed the data

```
params = {'maperiod': 15, 'printlog': False}
```

Now we can access the data by key

```
params['maperiod'] == 15
params['printlog'] == False
```

---

Sometimes we want the best of both worlds, both a tuple and we can access by key. This sounds like what the example was using since we access with `.` notation. For that we use namedtuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple
params = namedtuple('Params', 'maperiod, printlog')(15, False)
```

and access by index or by attribute

```
params[0] == params.maperiod == 15
params[1] == params.printlog == False
```

---

What is confusing is that you've mentioned all three in different ways. I'd go back and look at the example to see which one they are using and follow that.

---

Edit: If what you do have is a tuple then it is very easy to convert into a `dict` or `namedtuple` for easier accessing. Just do:

```
dict_params = dict(params)
nt_params = namedtuple('Params', [p[0] for p in params])(*[p[1] for p in params])
```

Comment: You can convert that tuple to a dict by just wrapping it in `dict`. So `params = dict(params)`. Then you can access by key. --- If that is how the data is written, then you **definitely** didn't access it as `self.params['printlog']`.